# SharedPrefs Null Pointer | Isn't that impossible?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I'm getting a null pointer on a shared pref. But shared prefs always require a default value. So wouldn't that make it impossible.

Adding this code snippet (roughly) gives me the problem (according to logcat):

```
myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", 0);
        String lvl_result= myPrefs
                .getString(lvl, null);
        // Example "A -> a" or null
        if (lvl_result.equals(null)) {
            gen_lvl();
            lvl_result = myPrefs.getString(lvl, null);
        }
```

Logcat (not sure if this is what you want to see):

```
12-04 00:54:42.932: E/AndroidRuntime(763): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: where you are getting NP ? If so then there is no key of that name through which you are accessing value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace following line in your code:

```
if (lvl_result.equals(null)) {
```

with

```
if (lvl_result == null) {
```

if the `lvl_result` is `null` then calling `equals` method on this object would raise the null pointer exception..